# How to Select Columns in Editors (Atom,Notepad++, Kate, VIM, Sublime, Textpad,etc) and IDEs (NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc)

Tags: ide, editor

How to select columns in Editors and IDEs to columnar delete, insert or replace some characters ?

Editors:

- Atom
- Notepad++
- Kate
- VIM
- Sublime
- Emacs
- Textpad
- Emerald Editor
- UltraEdit
- MCEdit
- jEdit
- Nedit

IDEs:

- NetBeans
- Eclipse
- Visual Studio
- IntelliJ IDEA
- Flash Builder
- Aptana Studio

Comment: Anyone who wants to add to the information here should create a new question for that specific editor (if one doesn't already exist) and answer _that_ question.  Giant lists like this have gotten unmanageable in the decade since this question was posted: turns out there are a lot of editors.  Who knew?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

- Notepad++, Visual Studio, and some others: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>drag</kbd>.
- vim: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> or (bizarrely enough) Quad-click-drag. In windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is the standard for paste)

Comment: Any chance you know how to select a columnar block of text using a mouse, and copy it to the system clipboard (either the middle-click-paste one, or the ctrl-v-paste one)?

Comment: Notepad++, Visual Studio, others: You can also use Shift + Alt + arrow keys to select columns without the mouse.

Comment: +1 for quad-click-drag. I know Vim users aren't "supposed" to use the mouse, but I think selecting with the mouse is sometimes useful.

Comment: For EditPlus,to select columnar block use Alt+C.

Comment: From an edit that should have been a comment: Be sure to toggle off "wrap long lines"

Comment: Alt+shift+arrowkeys ( up/down/left/right ) to select the specified Column

Answer (score 86):

In Kate toggle  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> .

Comment: FTR, this also applies to kdevelop.

Comment: Note this toggles, so to go back to the default selection mode you have to press `Ctrl + shift + B` again.

Comment: And it is called "Block Selection Mode" in Kate, if you, like me, were searching for it in the Edit menu.

Comment: Kate does not seem to support vertical insertion or am I doing something wrong ? I switched to "Block Selection Mode" then selected the first column of a series of lines (left of the first character) then typed something. It unexpectedly appeared only as a prefix to the last line !

Comment: Kate column insertion is available 4.12. check https://kate-editor.org/2013/09/09/multi-line-text-editing-in-kate/

Answer (score 62):

In Netbeans 7.1 can select columns (Rectangular Selection) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> . There is also a button [image: Toggle Rectangular Selection Button] in the code editor available.

This is how rectangular selections look like:
[image: Screenshot Rectangular Selection]

Comment: how can I indent a rectangular selection?

Comment: On Mac, it's `Cmd` + `shift` + `r`.

Comment: A more detailed and updated anwser can be found here: [Editing multiple lines of code in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885784/9620269)

Answer (score 38):

**Eclipse** used to need a [column mode plugin](http://tkilla.ch/column_mode/) to be able to select a rectangular selection.

[image: column mode]

Since Eclipse 3.5, you just need to type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: see its [News and Noteworthy](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-part1.html#Text) section. (On OS X it's Option-Command-A.)

[image: block (aka column or rectangular) selection mode]

> Or activate the '`Editor Presentation`' action set ( *Window > Customize Perspective* menu) to get a tool bar button for toggling the block selection mode.

[AmbroseChapel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242241/ambrosechapel) adds in the comments:

> **This is a toggle**.
>
> Columnar selection is a mode you enter and leave: in other words, Eclipse switches into a mode where all mouse selections have to be columnar and you stay in that mode until you switch back (by using the same command again).
> It's not like other editors where columnar selections are enabled only while certain keys are down.

Comment: Quick note: With Eclipse, this is a toggle. Columnar selection is a mode you enter and leave—in other words, Eclipse switches into a mode where all mouse selections have to be columnar and you stay in that mode until you switch back (by using the same command again). It's not like other editors where columnar selections are enabled only while certain keys are down.

Answer (score 22):

In vim column visual mode is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>. If that is what you meant?

Comment: The Windows version uses Ctrl + Q since Ctrl + V is the standard paste clipboard command.

Comment: @Andrew: It's worth noting that by "Windows version" you mean the default .vimrc that ships with gVim. The default vim behavior can be reverted to Ctrl+V by commenting out the appropriate line in $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim.

Answer (score 22):

## SublimeText 2, 3, and 4

### Using the Mouse

Different mouse buttons are used on each platform:

#### OS X

```
Left Mouse Button + Option
OR: Middle Mouse Button
Add to selection: Command
Subtract from selection: Command+Shift
```

#### Windows

```
Right Mouse Button + Shift
OR: Middle Mouse Button
Add to selection: Ctrl
Subtract from selection: Alt
```

#### Linux

```
Right Mouse Button + Shift
Add to selection: Ctrl
Subtract from selection: Alt
```

### Using the Keyboard

#### OS X

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

#### Windows

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

#### Linux

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

Source: [SublimeText2 Documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html)

Comment: Also for Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 16):

You didn't explicitly state emacs, but since you've highlighted lots of editors...

In emacs, you can use rectangles for this, where a column is a rectangle of width 1.

To create a rectangle, mark the top-left and bottom-right of the rectangle (where the bottom-right mark is one to the right of the further right point included in the rectangle. You can then manipulate via:

`C-x r k`
Kill the text of the region-rectangle, saving its contents as the "last killed rectangle" (`kill-rectangle`).

`C-x r d`
Delete the text of the region-rectangle (`delete-rectangle`).

`C-x r y`
Yank the last killed rectangle with its upper left corner at point (`yank-rectangle`).

`C-x r o`
Insert blank space to fill the space of the region-rectangle (`open-rectangle`). This pushes the previous contents of the region-rectangle rightward.

`M-x clear-rectangle`
Clear the region-rectangle by replacing its contents with spaces.

`M-x delete-whitespace-rectangle`
Delete whitespace in each of the lines on the specified rectangle, starting from the left edge column of the rectangle.

`C-x r t string RET`
Replace rectangle contents with string on each line. (`string-rectangle`).

`M-x string-insert-rectangle RET string RET`
Insert string on each line of the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Note that with cua-mode enabled, the C-x would cut the region, so one must substitute C-x C-x, or S-C-f.

Answer (score 11):

In **IntelliJ IDEA**, you can switch the selection mode with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> combination. You can also column select by keeping the middle mouse button (i.e. the scroll wheel button) pressed and dragging.

Answer (score 10):

on **Kate**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> also allows you to add more columns by simply clicking anywhere and paste it.

I used this when saving text files I copied from Google Translate as a side-by-side view.

Answer (score 7):

This feature is not available in [older versions of Netbeans (up to 7.1)](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13857) <s>and the plugin is not supported anymore</s>.

[A plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=33497) is now available for NetBeans 6.9.

Answer (score 6):

In TextMate with the mouse: start a selection and keep <kbd>alt</kbd> pressed while you move the cursor.

Without the mouse: first select normally using <kbd>⇧</kbd> and arrows then hit <kbd>alt</kbd> and move the cursor.

Answer (score 6):

in Notepad++ , you can select a particular column holding ctrl + alt + shift and then left click mouse button and drag to select.

Comment: There is actually no need to hold down Ctrl. Shift + Alt + dragging the mouse (or the arrow keys) is enough.

Answer (score 5):

In TextPad:

With the mouse, Left-Click + Alt + Drag. Note that if you first use Alt, and then Click-and-drag, it does not work (at least for me). Ctrl+Alt instead of Alt also Works.

For pure keyboard, no mouse, enable Block Select Mode with Ctrl+Q, B.
Or use the sequence Alt, C, B, to do it via the Configure menu.

Warning 1: if Word Wrap is enabled, then Block Select Mode will not be available (which is somewhat logical). First disable Word Wrap. This was causing me some trouble, and [this](http://www.ztw3.com/forum/forum_entry.php?id=110911) gave me the answer.

Warning 2: if you mean to insert text in every selected row by typing, you have to use Edit, Fill Block. Other editors let you type in directly.

Answer (score 4):

In [Ultra Edit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) and [Crimson (or Emerald) Editor](http://www.emeraldeditor.com/) you can enable/disable the column mode with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

In textpad.

Go to left top of the page.
hold "shift key 
Now use right arrow key to select column.
Now click "down arrow" key.
And the entire column will be selected.

Comment: To enable "block select mode", use CTRL+Q then B. Same again to turn off.

Comment: In my version of textpad pressing down didn't select the whole column but in block select mode I could quickly select the column with shift-page down.  Much quicker than alt-select on the mouse

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Nedit under Cygwin-X (or any platform for that matter), hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while selecting text with the left mouse.

Additionally, you can then drag the selected "box" around in an insert mode using the depressed left-mouse button or in overwrite mode by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left-mouse button</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

jEdit:

With the keyboard: press <kbd>Alt-\</kbd> (<kbd>Opt-\</kbd> in Mac OS X) to toggle between rectangular and normal selection mode; then use <kbd>Shift</kbd> plus arrow keys to extend selection. You can switch back to regular selection mode with another <kbd>Alt-\</kbd> (<kbd>Opt-\</kbd> in Mac OS X), if desired.

With the mouse: Either use <kbd>Alt-\</kbd> (<kbd>Opt-\</kbd> in Mac OS X) as above to toggle rectangular selection mode, then drag as usual; or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-drag (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-drag in Mac OS X). You can switch back to regular selection mode with another <kbd>Alt-\</kbd> (<kbd>Opt-\</kbd> in Mac OS X), if desired.

Actually, you can even make a non-rectangular selection the normal way and then hit <kbd>Alt-\</kbd> (<kbd>Opt-\</kbd> in Mac OS X) to convert it into a rectangular one.

Answer (score 3):

In MCEdit toggle <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (ie <kbd>F13</kbd>) or <kbd>F9</kbd>->Edit ->Mark columns.

P.S. In this case, MCEdit is an editor written for the Midnight Commander.

Answer (score 3):

In Sublime3 (Windows):

Some users may get an inverted screen using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>▲</kbd> in windows. To Solve this go to

Preferences->Key Bindings-User

And add these two lines at the end of the file just before closing brackets:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+pageup"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },

{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+pagedown"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} }
```

Or use your own keys.

Comment: This should rather be a comment on [Mart Van de Ven's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13796939/3982001), not an independent one.

Answer (score 2):

In Flash Builder (v 4.5 and up), and Aptana Studio (at least v 2.0.5) there is a toolbar button to toggle block select. It is between the 'mark occurrences' and 'show whitespace characters' buttons. There is also a <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> shortcut. Not surprisingly, this is basically the same as for Eclipse, but I'm including here for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

With **Nedit** you can do several operations with selected column:

CTRL+LEFT-MOUSE                                -> Mark Rectangular Text-Area

MIDDLE-MOUSE            pressed in area        -> moving  text area with pushing aside other text

CTRL+MIDDLE-MOUSE       pressed in marked area -> moving  text area with overriding aside text and deleting text from original position

CTRL+SHIFT+MIDDLE-MOUSE pressed in marked area -> copying text area with overriding aside text and keeping  text from original position

Answer (score 0):

For any editor, you can use the below shortcuts. These shortcuts work for every text area also.

**`Shift + UpArrow/DownArrow`** - this will select text line by line

**`Ctrl + Shift + LeftArrow/RightArrow`** - this will select text word by word

**`Ctrl + BackSpace`** - this will delete text word by word