# Eclipse: Can you put your cursor on all lines?

Tags: eclipse, text-editor

In IDEA you had the possibility to put your cursor on all lines.

Is this possible in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you meant. Is it something like block editing?

Comment: Let's say I found a piece of code on the net, but the code has the line numbers on every line of the text. In IDEA, you could delete those lines from 2-3 presses of del button, by putting the cursor on column mode (this is name I think)

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse 3.5  should have a column mode (which is what I think you're asking about) - use `Alt+Shift+A`:

- http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-part1.html#Text

I haven't tried this since I'm stuck at version 3.4.1 for the time being.  There's a patch that claims to work for 3.4.0 (http://tkilla.ch/column_mode/), but it's not working for my 3.4.1 install.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the ability to select a group of lines (like a all function), you can use the outline view

[alt text http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/whatsNew/images/drag-and-drop-outline.png](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/whatsNew/images/drag-and-drop-outline.png)

From there, you can move/rearrange/delete all block of text.

---

If it is about column mode, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802616/how-to-select-column-in-editors-notepad-kate-vim-netbeans-eclips/1803266#1803266).

[alt text http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/images/block-selection-mode.png](http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/images/block-selection-mode.png)