# Block selection in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Does anyone know if block selection (or rectangular selection) is possible in eclipse?
Maybe there's a plugin? I haven't been able to find one myself yet...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838432/eclipse-can-you-put-your-cursor-on-all-lines/1838557#1838557

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable the column selection mode in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Column mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053725/4210) is in Eclipse 3.5. The linked site also contains a patch for 3.4.0 (only).

Comment: Also discussed here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse

Comment: Wish they will add a way to auto enable block selection with Alt + Selection like other modern code editors.

Answer (score 83):

Block selection is available since Eclipse 3.5.
You can toggle between standard and block selection using:

<kbd>**Alt**</kbd> + <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**A**</kbd>
    <kbd>**Opt**</kbd> + <kbd>**Cmd**</kbd>   + <kbd>**A**</kbd> (on Mac)

or press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**3**</kbd> (<kbd>**Cmd**</kbd>+<kbd>**3**</kbd> on Mac), type "toggle block" and select Toggle Block Selection command.

Comment: If you're using Mac, it's `Alt + Cmd + A`

Comment: No such thing as `Alt` on Mac. Try `Opt`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are on a mac you can use `option+command+A`

Answer (score 9):

Use `Ctrl+3` and write "block" in popup.

You can also use shortcut `Alt+Shift+A`. You can always see list of shortcuts with `Ctrl+Shift+L`. Block selection shortcut is on the bottom of this list.

Answer (score 1):

- Press Alt + Shift + A
- Observe that the screen zooms out
- Make selection using the mouse
- Press Alt + Shift + A to go back to the old mode.

[image]