# Select subset of characters in many lines (column selection) in Eclipse/Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, selection

How to select subset of characters in many lines (column selection) in Eclipse/Android Studio?
Ideally without plugins. Shift+Alt+A seems not to be working for me either.

In Notepad++ you can do it with Shift+Alt+(Arrows) or Alt+Left_Mouse (and drag to select)

Please see example below (Column selection I'm after):

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [softwareninjaneer.com](http://softwareninjaneer.com/images/StreamAndColumnSelectionModes.png))</sub>

Visual Studio and many other tools support it.

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7862385/115145

Comment: Android Studio: try http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I use android studio. You can switch between selection mode by:
<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>insert</kbd>, or Edit -> Column selection mode.

[source](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/30-days-with-intellij-idea-editor-basics/).

Comment: For Mac the key shortcut is: command-shift-8  See: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d1404288e223

You can also hold alt and drag with left mouse button to do column select

Comment: Also worth noting, as I am having trouble remembering the non-similar combinations across multiple platforms:  If you hold alt, then click and drag, you can column-select without being in column-select mode =)

Answer (score 38):

Without any command you can get selection mode by using mouse drag with press Alt in **Android Studio**,

**Mouse: Alt+MouseDrag**

Answer (score 10):

Now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left_Mouse works in Android Studio.

Answer (score 10):

Android Studio column selection on the Mac Book you can use this Shortcut
Mac :

> **Cmd + Shift + 8**

source [here](https://github.com/pavlospt/Android-Studio-Tips-by-Philippe-Breault/wiki/Column-Selection)

Answer (score 3):

To enter column selection mode, press <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>insert</kbd>.

To get the caret to occupy multiple lines, simply hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the up or down arrow key. Then you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the right or left key to select text horizontally like you usually would.

To exit column selection mode, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of previous answers, but this might be easier or more straightforward as compared to memorizing key shortcuts.

Just Right-click while the cursor is inside a file/class, then select/deselect '**column selection mode**' from the list of options that appears (usually the fifth option on the list)

Answer (score 0):

As per this thread:
[How do I enable the column selection mode in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse)

or this one: [Block selection in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914492/block-selection-in-eclipse)

Use: **Alt+Shift+A**

To switch between Column selection ans stream selection.

Block selection is available since Eclipse 3.5. You can toggle between standard and block selection by Alt+Shift+A (or press Ctrl+3, type "toggle block" and select Toggle Block Selection command).

Answer (score 0):

the short cut key to select more column character: shift+up or down arrow (define more line) then shift +left or right arrow for select text