# How to select a text intelligently in a text editor?

Tags: editor

So I have a text say

```
Hello I am going to be late tonight.
Do not go outside.
```

And I would like to select:

```
Hello I 
Do not
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Depends on the editor, though.

Comment: Thanks. Let say notepad++?

Comment: In Notepad++, hold `Alt` and select with the mouse.

Comment: @Chiba: Be more specific while asking questions

Comment: @mps I did not know that it depends on editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below links explain exactly what you are looking for.

In notepad++,

use `Alt + Mouse` and drag or

```
Alt + Shift + Arrow keys
```

for selecting column  wise and editing.

[Column Mode Editing](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html)

In vim use `ctrl-v` for selecting column wise.

[text selection](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/vim/selection.html)

You can also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802616/how-to-select-columns-in-editors-notepad-kate-vim-sublime-textpad-etc-an) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vim, you can do column-wise selection with Ctrl-v

Comment: Thank you my friend. Do you know what to do if I am using any other editor? Can I find some documentation on the website of the editor?

Comment: Yes, and it will completely depend on the editor.  Not all editors will allow you to do this.