# Edit columns by pasting multiple lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, multiple-columns

NPP is an awesome tool. Im just looking if the following can be achieved in notepad++

The source data is:

```
123
abc
xyz
```

Also I have some data as

```
9
8
7
```

I want the data in the following format using Notepad ++

```
1293
ab8c
xy7z
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1802616/2449192

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [column select mode](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html)

1. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and select the `9 8 7`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
3. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the cursor down the column where you want the values inserted
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>