# Grouping by all non-aggregated columns in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have two tables `PO` and `PO_Line` and I want to list all fields from `PO` plus the quantity of rows from `PO_Line` that link back to each row in `PO` I would write a query something like -

```
SELECT
  PO.propA,
  PO.propB,
  PO.propC,
  PO.propD,
  PO.propE,
  ...
  PO.propY,
  COUNT(PO_Line.propA) LINES
FROM
  PO
LEFT JOIN
  PO_Lines
ON
  PO.ID = PO_Lines.PO_ID
```

Obviously this would give an error someting along the lines of -

> Column 'PO.propA' is invaalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So to get the query to run I will add a `GROUP BY` clause to the end of the query and copy and paste my select lines, like so -

```
SELECT
  PO.propA,
  PO.propB,
  PO.propC,
  PO.propD,
  PO.propE,
  ...
  PO.propY,
  COUNT(PO_Line.propA) LINES
FROM
  PO
LEFT JOIN
  PO_Lines
ON
  PO.ID = PO_Lines.PO_ID
GROUP BY
  PO.propA,
  PO.propB,
  PO.propC,
  PO.propD,
  PO.propE,
  ...
  PO.propY
```

Which works perfectly however it all feels a little unwieldy, especially if I've named my columns i.e. -

```
SELECT
  PO.propA AS 'FIRST PROPERTY',
  PO.propB AS 'SECOND PROPERTY',
  PO.propC AS 'THIRD PROPERTY',
  PO.propD AS 'ANOTHER PROPERTY',
  PO.propE AS 'YOU GET THE IDEA',
  ...
  PO.propY
```

and I have to copy/paste the entries from the select clause and then delete the column names.

So my question is - Is there a shorthand method to say group by all non-aggregated entries found in the select clause?

Comment: You can do a SELECT on just the aggregate columns and the non-aggregate key fields, and then JOIN to another SELECT DISTINCT of the rest of the non-aggregate fields.  This is also unwieldy, but it has the advantage of allowing you to do SELECT *, rather than explicitly listing all of the non-aggregate fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want window functions:

```
SELECT . . .,
       COUNT(PO_Line.propA) OVER (PARTITION BY PO.ID) as LINES
FROM PO LEFT JOIN
     PO_Lines
     ON PO.ID = PO_Lines.PO_ID;
```

Comment: This might return a lot of duplicated rows assuming that the select is only getting columns from `PO`.

Answer (score 1):

> *I have to copy/paste the entries from the select clause and then delete the column names.*

I strongly suggest to use [block/column selection](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2786/column-and-block-text-selection-using-sql-server-management-studio/).Move `,` as first element and allign your aliases:

```
SELECT
   PO.propA AS 'FIRST PROPERTY'
  ,PO.propB AS 'SECOND PROPERTY'
  ,PO.propC AS 'THIRD PROPERTY'
  ,PO.propD AS 'ANOTHER PROPERTY'
  ,PO.propE AS 'YOU GET THE IDEA'
  ...
  ,PO.propY
  ,COUNT(PO_Line.propA) LINES
FROM  PO
LEFT JOIN  PO_Lines
  ON  PO.ID = PO_Lines.PO_ID
GROUP BY
   ...
```

[image]

In `SQL Server Management Studio` use simple block selection <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> highlight and paste.

If you are using other editor find corresponding keyshortcut  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802616/how-to-select-columns-in-editors-notepad-kate-vim-sublime-textpad-etc-an).

It is nice for multiple edit at once like adding schema, alias, ...and so on.

Comment: Most halfway capable editors (at least on Windows) use Alt for block selection; this even works in MS Word! ;)

Comment: Still a little awkward as you need to format your `SELECT` clause so that when you have fields with differing length names they all need to line up but saying that I have learned something new!

Comment: @JohnC That is why you should use tools like [`Redgate`](http://www.red-gate.com/assets/INTERIM/assets/products/sql-prompt/images/one-click-sql-formatting.png) or `Apex` that will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your query I think you might not need a `GROUP BY` to begin with:

```
SELECT
  PO.propA,
  PO.propB,
  PO.propC,
  PO.propD,
  PO.propE,
  ...
  PO.propY,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PO_Lines WHERE PO.ID = PO_Lines.PO_ID) LINES
FROM
  PO
```